# Python code to copy formula value from .xlsm file to .xlsx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx, xlsm

I have a few .xlsm files in a directory.
I want to write a python code that creates new .xlsx files in that directory that having the same file names as the xlsm files (just xlsx instead of xlsm).

The xlsm files have a simple formula in cell Q1. It just sums a few cells. (like Q1 is  =A1+B1).
I want to copy the **result of the sum** in Q1 of the xlsm to the corresponding xlsx file, and it should be a constant number in the xlsx file, not a formula (since the rest of the xlsx sheet is empty).

All what I try to do, it doesn't copy the result as a constant number. It copies it as a formula, and then the value in the xlsx file is wrong (since it doesn't have the rest of the data to make the calculation).

Here is my python code, what should I change so it will copy the result just as a constant number?

(edit: probably in the future I'll make the formula in Q1 more complicated, and maybe copy more cells with different formulas.. so I'm looking for a solution that will copy the data itself, not a solution that makes calculations in xlsx file by using the values in xlsm files.

Edit2: Only these specific cells are copied. It does not copy the whole xlsm files to the xlsx files)

Thanks

```
import os
import openpyxl

for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.xlsm'):
        xlsm_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        xlsm_sheet = xlsm_wb.active
        xlsx_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
        xlsx_sheet = xlsx_wb.active
   
        xlsx_sheet['Q1'] = xlsm_sheet['Q1'].value
    
        xlsx_wb.save(filename[:-1] + 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replicate the formula in Python. Ex. add in a line that says:

```
xlsx_sheet['Q'] = xlsx_sheet['A'] + xlsx_sheet['B']
```

And it will replace the formulas it imported with the results of the replicated formula.

Comment: But what if later i'll create a more difficult formula, and maybe want to copy more cells with formulas?
I'm sure there should be a way to copy the value itself..